# Is it better to use USB A or USB B or RS232 to communicate over long distances?

Tags: serial, rfid

[Similar post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187633/max-serial-cable-length)

As per the previous post (which was 5 years ago), I have a [device](https://www.alientechnology.com/products/readers/alr-f800/) that has three forms of serial communication. One is an RS232, the other is USB A and finally a USB B. So I have three options to connect my PC to this device. The device sends the scanned RFID tags through this serial connection to my PC.

I want to place the reader 60 meters away from my PC. Which type of serial communication should I use?

Comment: This was already well answered at the question you linked: [Max Serial Cable Length?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187633/max-serial-cable-length)  It should take you no more than a few seconds web search to realize that USB is a *short range* scheme.  A explained at the link, you can try RS232 or convert it to an even longer range differential standard.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that is a similar post in my question that is clearly shown. In addition, this question is different because I trying to find out which is better, USB A, USB B or RS232. This clearly differentiates my question from the previous post. Not sure how much more clear I can be.

Comment: As explained above, if you'd done even the slightest bit of the required self research before posting you would have found out that USB is a short range standard compared to what you learned about RS232 at your own link.   Additionally, even the *topic matter* of this question is off-topic: this is a *usage* question not an *electronic design* question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton then why was not the other question closed down?

Comment: Doing a google search for "USB cable length", I find many sites stating that USB is llimited to 5 metres/16 ft.

Comment: USB is limited to 5 meters (about 16 feet) per link. You can extend this by using active repeater cables -- essentially 1-port hubs -- but then you run into the limit on the number of hubs (4, IIRC). So the only viable choice in your list is RS-232.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you

Comment: You can buy a PCBs that will convert RS232 into RS485 and back. RS485 is much better suited to long distance connections like yours.

Comment: @ChrisStratton please address the other post. Clearly this is creating a lot of inconsistencies on this platform. Makes it seems that there are no rules.

Comment: USB A and USB B are only the connector spec. They're both the same USB on the wires.

Comment: @Drew 1220 meters is definitely enough. Thank you.

Comment: Is it not possible to do SSH via virtual serial port or Raspberry Pi to help you interface with your device from a distance?

Comment: more than 20 years ago, I was at TI Germany. The guys there told me, they just archived more than 50 meters RS232 with their best chip in laboratory conditions - and I do not remember the speed. I would consider 60m of RS232 not something practical. You want a differential bus, like RS422/485, CAN, (M-)LVDS, Ethernet. Each of them will do 60m. Or search for a glasfiber converter. They are common for EMV test chambers and also should do 60m with ease

Answer (score 3):

The solutions is not that many. But first, is it a option to move the "ALR-F800" closer to the RF reader since it is a Ethernet and PoE device?

Otherwise is the solution only RS232 and at low bit rate. And what bitrate ? It depends mainly on two factors, distance and electrical interference (EMC) from electrical and electronic devices in the proximity to the cable, thus it could be reduced with a god shielded cable.